# If $Tr(A^k)=0$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ is $A^n=0_n$, where $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I know that the relation $Tr(A^k)=0$ is equivalent to $\sum_1^n(\alpha_i^k)=0$ where $\alpha_i$ is an eigenvalue of A and that $\alpha_i=0$ for any i is a solution to the system, but is it unique?

Edit: I forgot to specify the size of the matrix the first time around

Comment: Of course not, you can surely find other collections of $k$-th powers that add to $0$ if $k$ is odd (but even if it is even, you can using complex numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take, as per edit, that we are talking $n \times n$ matrices.

Yes, because of [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials).

They imply that all the elementary symmetric functions in the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$, so the [characteristic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of $A$ is $x^n$.

Comment: Nope, you need the trace to be zero up to the size of the matrix.

Comment: @Jim, ok, but this seems implicit in the notation $0_{n}$. Will edit, though - it's been spelled out in the title right now.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the subscript on the $n$.

Comment: do Newton's identities guarantee the uniqueness of the solution of any symmetrical system of n equations with the eigenvalues of A?

Comment: @user65469, sorry, I don't understand (no doubt my fault). Please clarify, in case we might move to chat.

Comment: well here I had $Tr(A^k)=0$, but what if the values of the traces were given but weren't all 0, and I found a solution to the system. Is that solution unique?

Comment: @user65469, now I see. Well, using Newton's identities iteratively (as they are listed in the Wikipedia article) you can reconstruct in any case the elementary symmetric functions, hence the characteristic polynomial. So the characteristic polynomial is uniquely determined by the values $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)$, for $1 \le k \le n$.

Comment: @user65469, you're welcome.